# Return all remote matches with typeahead without extra filtering

Tags: javascript, typeahead, bloodhound

Can't seem to figure out a way to disable filtering with typeahead. Basically I just need the autocomplete (or rather drop-down search hint) functionality of it. I am doing a zip code search and resulting postal codes don't necessarily match the queried ones. How do I make it show all matches without doing extra filtering on those again?

Below is the code I have:

```
var dealers = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (d) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: '/form/find-dealer?postalCode=',
        prepare: function (query, settings) {
            settings.url += encodeURIComponent(query);
            settings.type = 'POST';
            settings.contentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
            return settings;
       }
    }
});

$('input[name=postalCode]').typeahead({
    minLength: 3
}, {
    name: 'dealers',
    display: function (data) {
        return data.title;
    },
    source: dealers.ttAdapter()
});
```

**Note:** I know it seems a bit awkward to do a zip code search that way, but the purpose of the designer was for users to search interchangeably by dealer name and zip code.

**Additional Info:** typeahead.bundle.js - v0.11.1

Comment: "resulting postal codes don't necessarily match the queried ones" looks like you want to show all zipcodes no matter what the user types.... "How do I make it show all matches" seems like you want to match what user types. Please clarify what you want. A demo may be useful. Also, what version of the plugin are you using?

Comment: @yezzz, typeahead.bundle.js - v0.11.1. I would like to show all objects retured with AJAX call (all other magic is already happening on the server side)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not pretty, since the library has been forked and no longer oficially supported by the creator, but this fix did it for me https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/pull/1212 . Basically when in remote mode, it returns all matches, which is actually the proper behavior as I see it.

This SO thread helped [twitter typeahead ajax results not all shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798859/twitter-typeahead-ajax-results-not-all-shown)

Answer (score 2):

If you want send a query to AJAX & get data from your database & add all JSON result for result of typehead (You have a data filter with database & send clean data with AJAX & JSON, But type head has extra filtering & don't show anything or some of your data), You must do it :

Open bootstrap-typeahead.js & find

```
item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase())
```

And replace it to :

```
item.toLowerCase().indexOf(item.toLowerCase())
```

Will you can show all results from Ajax JSON ...

Comment: I can't find : item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase()) in js file. where it's exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems showing all without any (matching) query isn't possible:
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1308

Though some are trying it with minlength=0 like this:
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1251

And it looks it was possible in an older version:
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/pull/719

Btw the plugin is no longer being developed and the manual is incomplete. An improved one can be found at this fork: https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js/tree/master/doc

Having said that, you may be better off with another autosuggest, or a plugin like select2, which does show results by default and can use external sources.

Comment: Thanks for the research and the answer, but I still believe it is doable via providing custom function as a `source` for the datasets (`jQuery#typeahead(options, [*datasets])`).

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know when you succeed. Good luck.